# SearchView moves to the left after clicking on it and does not show search field until clicked again

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

I'm using a SearchView to filter my list view.

I'm using `android:iconifiedByDefault="true"`in combination with `app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"`.

The problem:

1) If I open the fragment, I can click on the iconified search action (see [screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVy71.png)).

2) The search icon now moves to the left, BUT the search field is missing ([screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FB5Zt.png)).

3) Only if I do a second click on that moved icon, the search field will show up correctly (no screenshot due to stackoverflow's limitation of users with <10 reputations).

And, important: When the fragment is opened for the first time, the above happens.
If I close the search view then and open it again without leaving the fragment, the search field will appear right after the first click, but won't get the focus (so the keyboard comes up).

It has something to do with `collapseActionView`. Without it, everything's working as expected (but the searchfield will then overlay my other icon in the appbar..).

Is this a bug or is something in my code causing this behaviour?

Comment: Solution: use android.support.v7.widget.SearchView instead of google's suggested android.widget.SearchView. Now everything works like a charm

Comment: Google suggested that here: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/search/setup.html It's horribly outdated, because besides the above, the mentionend android:actionViewClass there will give you a nullpointer..use app: instead.

Comment: the first comment helped me, I think it should be an accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

for androidx: `app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"`

pre androidx: `app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"`

```
<item android:id="@+id/search"
      android:title="@string/search_label"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
      app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"
      app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"/>
```